# Is there a limit to Laravel POST inputs?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

In my controller when I do `$request->all()` to get all my inputs from the form, it does not outputs all the inputs. Even though it's supposed to have 146 key->value pair, it's always limiting to 56.

````
```
  array:56 [▼
  "_token" => "ZgjRs0eg0WN9fgqylFd348kUcJErej0VBaSEcDf1"
  "current_user" => "default@default.com"
  "Devices" => ""
  "Device:598" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:599" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:432" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:267" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:3860" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:2414" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:2413" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:2416" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:2415" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:2418" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:2417" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:2422" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:505" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:56" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:512" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:1032" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:3681" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:4851" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:843" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:54" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:561" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:516" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:439" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:4850" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:2421" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:488" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:612" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:65" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:239" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:147" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:514" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:617" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:2423" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:142" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:613" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:141" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:508" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:4856" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:55" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:4857" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:842" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:1134" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:161" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:1135" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:509" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:511" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:163" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:246" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:2424" => array:18 [▶]
  "Device:2425" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:139" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:243" => array:20 [▶]
  "Device:510" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
```
````

And it only happens on my ubuntu server. My localhost works fine. What's causing the issue?

Comment: Yes though the limit is not specific to laravel. Check settings for Max input vars and Max post size.

Comment: do you use var_dump ? because var_dump limits the output.. you can write output to a file using file_put_contents to see real result.

Comment: `max_input_vars = 100000`  and `post_max_size = 8M`. I'm using dd() to output it

Comment: @bishop what do I need to change?

Comment: Everything looks fine with PHP settings. I'd first check the network tab of your browser to see what the raw request is: ensure it's actually sending all the data you think it is.

Answer (score 8):

Fixed it. I was editing `/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini` instead of `/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini`. Now after changing `max_input_vars = 20000`, it works.